Why cannot access cookie from middleware nextjs 14 on live site?
I have problems with my code middleware of nextjs 14
I testing on my local it is working very nice but on live site i cannot access coockie
This is my code middleware
import { decryptCookieData } from '@Utils/decrypt';
import { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import { paths } from '@/constants';
import { Role } from '@/enums/role';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname }: { pathname: string } = request.nextUrl;
  const cookie = request.cookies.get('_rr');
  const decrypted: JwtPayload = decryptCookieData(cookie?.value || '');

  if (decrypted?.role == Role.SUPPER_ADMIN) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (
    pathname === paths.upload ||
    pathname === paths.management ||
    pathname === paths.adminDashboard
  ) {
    if (decrypted?.role == Role.ADMIN) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(paths.notHaveAccessPage, request.url));
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/admin/:path*'],
};

Anyone can explain this problem and how can i fix it ?
Thank you

Can you check if you are getting any cookie? console.log('Cookies:', request.cookies.getAll())

yes, on my local it log my cookie but on live site it not log anything :((

Are cookies stored on browser on live site?

yes, i save store cookies on production
